# Замена функции sqrt с целью ускорения

Tags: c, алгоритм

Добрый день!

Есть ли возможность заменить в Си функцию SQRT на что-то более быстрое? 
Необходимо много миллионов раз вычислять:

```
distance = sqrt((delta_x*delta_x)+(delta_y*delta_y)+(delta_z*delta_z));
```

Хочется оптимизировать, может кто знает как?

Comment: А типы данных какие? Можно от чисел с плавающей точкой перейти к числам с фиксированной точкой. Или вообще к целым. В зависимости от того каковы условия задачи. Напоминаю, что целочисленная арифметика всяко быстрее, чем арифметика чисел с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 4):

Вот асм код для sqrt

```
FLD     X
FSQRT
FWAIT
```

Быстрее ничего нету. Хотя, насколько я знаю, в Си реализовано также.

Лучше попробуйте оптимизировать цикл.

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто. Работайте с квадратами расстояний:

```
distanceSqr = ((delta_x * delta_x)+(delta_y * delta_y)+(delta_z * delta_z));
```

Судя по всему, вас интересуют длины векторов. Так обычно с ними и работают.

**Добавление.**

Вообще, в Си можно асм-вставки делать, наверное, ничего быстрее асмовых функций уже не придумаете. Для возведения в произвольную вещественную степень можно использовать логарифмы:

```
a^b = exp(b* ln(a))
```

Асм уже плохо помню, но помнится, что fpu считает такое довольно быстро (по сути это два разложения в ряды Тейлора, что в общем случае быстрее метода последовательных приближений, который скорей всего юзается в sqrt).

Comment: Пробовал это, но дальнейшие вычисления требуют нечётной степени. Т.е. необходимо возведение в дробную степень, что тоже работает небыстро.

Comment: не врубился, как это связано с извлечением корня. вообще в Си можно асм-вставки делать, наверно ничего быстрее асмовых функций уже не придумаете. для возведения в произвольную вещественную степень можно использовать логарифмы:<br>
a^b = exp(b* ln(a)),<br>
асм уже плохо помню, но помнится, что fpu считает такое довольно быстро.
<br><br>
p.s.: посмотрел вот, в гугле полно инфы по fast sqrt ваще-то.. можно начать отсюда<br>
http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=39664<br>
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.14/14.01/FastSquareRootCalc/

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать подобрать аппроксимацию, которая будет в заданном диапазоне приближать эту функцию. Например, можно взять большую таблицу (кубическую), отобразить аргументы в индексы, по ним рассчитать таблицу, а уже во время основных расчетов из таблицы извлекать рассчитанные загодя значения. Если интервал значений невелик и требуемая точность не приводит к колоссальным объемам необходимой памяти, будет ускорение.

Answer (score 0):

Если подойдет приблизительная точность, можно воспользоваться «[быстрым инверсным квадратным корнем](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)». Там также есть реализация на Си. Так как корень инверсный, то чтобы получить нормальный корень, нужно на него разделить единицу.